# How to insert and delete the realm database in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

This i my code to insert data on realm database.

```
 LocalBackupRealm *fullBackup=[[LocalBackupRealm alloc] init];
 realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
 [realm beginWriteTransaction];
 fullBackup.firstName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
 fullBackup.lastName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
 fullBackup.RecordID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",RecordID];
 fullBackup.phoneIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneIdentifier];
 fullBackup.userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userName];
 fullBackup.phoneNumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneNumber];
 fullBackup.jobTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jobTitle];
 NSLog(@"%@ Data Base Values",fullBackup);
 [realm addObject:fullBackup];
 [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

But when i delete all the data form the realm database then app will crashed.

```
 [realm beginWriteTransaction];
 [realm deleteAllObjects];
 [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, what error message you get before the crash?

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for reply.
Can i know how to pass data to RLMArray

Comment: please check out the docs at: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#collections